# horizontal angle of view based on distance from window

Tags: geometry

I am looking for an equation to provide me the angle of view based on a distance from a window. I'm only interested in the horizontal not the vertical.

Comment: What do you mean by "angle of view"? Could you [edit] your question with a sketch? Can we assume the observer is always looking straight at the window or might they be off the window's perpendicular axis?

Comment: Good question. If I was standing in the same position as the window I would have an "angle of view" of 180 degrees. There is a wall either side of the window and you can't see past that (i.e. behind yourself) That wouldn't be physically possible but hopefully that answers your query. When you are up against the window your angle of view is at it's maximum and as you move back it reduces. I was assuming always looking straight out the window but if the answer could include other angles that would be a bonus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is basic trignometry. Use the *tan* function, $ tan\ \theta = \frac o a $ where *o* is the opposite (half the window width) and *a* is the adjacent (the distance to the window).

$$ \theta = 2 \ tan^{-1}(\frac w 2 \times \frac 1 d) $$

where $w$ = window width and $d$ = distance to window.

Comment: Does that give an answer in radians?

Comment: It depends what units your calculator is using. Degrees and radians are most common.

Comment: This is not a simple plug-and-chug, there a domain/range considerations that need to be adjusted for. Example: the maximum angle of view is obtained at the window (w=0), but tan^-1(0)=0, not pi as desired.

Comment: @electronpusher, even with your nose pressed against the glass your eyeballs will be some distance from it - but feel free to post a better answer. Note that at the window it's *d* that will be approaching zero, not *w*. That makes the solution tend towards $ 2tan^{-1}(\infty) = \pi $ as far as I know.

Comment: I see, my mistake

Comment: @electronpusher: No problem. You made me check though!